# dangerous to select fields in MongoDB Doctrine?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm not sure whether this is my fault. But I find that select fields in mongodb doctrine queries can lead to horrible consequence.

For example, I have a Page document like:

```
class Page
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    private $nbClicks = 0;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    private $nbShares = 0;

    // other fields ...
}
```

I may write some query like

```
$queryBuilder->select('title')->getQuery()->execute();
```

And somewhere behind this I do

```
$dm->flush();
```

nbClicks and nbShares of Pages I retrieved earlier are set to 0.

Is this something expected or might be a bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Wait so what is the workflow of your app? Can you provide a code example of what your explaining, if you `flush` and then do the query your `nbShares` and `nbClciks` will be 0 because you have no fetched them from DB, select is projection in MongoDB, whereby fiels are left out of the result

Comment: select first, then flush somewhere later. nbShares and nbClicks will be updated to 0 in DB.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a bug whereby doctrine is not storing the state of the projected document